# Java MongoDB collection.insert returns null for spock unit test

Tags: java, mongodb, unit-testing, groovy, spock

I am writing a unit test case to verify my method insertToCollection is working fine or not.

**InsertToMongoCollection.java**

```
protected void insertToCollection() {
   collection.insert(recordList);
}
```

**SPOCK:**

```
def "InsertToMongoCollection"() {
   given:
   Record record = new Record()
   record.setId("111")
   Collection collection= Mock()
   InsertToMongoCollection.collection = collection

   when:
   InsertToMongoCollection.addToGroup(record) // this inserts into recordList
   List<Record> result = collection.insertToCollection()

   then:
   result.count() == 1
}
```

The mocking is done correctly and the `recordList` also has 1 record. If I debug and see. But when the `collection.insert` is called, the result is null.

Answer (score 0):

`insertToCollection` had a `void` return type, so will return null when you do

```
List<Record> result = collection.insertToCollection()
```

Change the return type of the method so you can test it, or run up a fake mongo, and check the records are inserted

Comment: I tried to keep a debugger on `collection.insertToCollection()` in JAVA method and tried running the expression mannually.

Comment: JAVA:
protected void insertGroupToRepository() {
        List<DomFare> result = domFareRepository.insert(recordList);
        log.info("Result: {}",result);
    }
[main] INFO  com.XXX.XXX - Result: null

Comment: Tried a functional test separately.. and that runs fine using embeded mongo.

Comment: Ps: fongo is good for this situation: https://github.com/fakemongo/fongo/blob/master/README.md

Comment: And the reason you're seeing null in the Java method is that whatever insert is, it's probably another void method